# How to Combine multiple rows value into one row of another table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I know my question title is not right, sorry for that. What i really want to do is:
I have 2 table namely Account Table and History table as follows-
Account Table

```
BranchID  | AccountNo
101       |  123456
102       |  123456
102       |  123457
```

History Table

```
BranchID |  AccountNo   EmployeeName  | EmployeeType
101      |   123456   |   Mr. ABC     |   PMO
101     |    123456   |  Mr. TRY      |   RO
101     |    123456   |   Mr. OPR     |   Ref
102      |   123456   |   Mr. WER     |   PMO
102      |   123456   |   Mr. CVB     |   Ref
102      |   123457   |   Mr. QSR     |   PMO
102      |   123457   |   Mr. LIT     |   RO
102     |    123457   |   Mr. GHK     |   Ref
```

I want a combined result as-

```
BranchID  | AccountNo | PMOName |   ROName |    RefName
101       |  123456   | Mr. ABC | Mr. TRY  |   Mr. OPR
102       |  123456   | Mr. WER |          |    Mr. CVB
102       |  123457   | Mr. QSR | Mr. LIT  |   Mr. GHK
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What query have to tried writing so far ?

Comment: You are looking for `listagg()`

Comment: use inner join on both table with Account Table.BranchID=History Table.BranchID and select column contains BranchID  | AccountNo | PMOName |   ROName |    RefName
it is sql concept by the way.

Comment: SELECT t1.BranchID, t1.AccountNo
max(decode(ji.ro_type_id, '001', ji.employee_code, 'NA')) as pmo,
max(decode(ji.ro_type_id, '001', ji.employee_nm, 'NA')) as pmo,
max(decode(ji.ro_type_id, '002', ji.employee_code, 'NA')) as rm
FROM Account t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.BranchID, t.AccountNo, t.EmployeeName FROM History t 
GROUP BY t.BranchID, t.AccountNo, t.EmployeeName)t2 ON t2.BranchID=t1.BranchID AND t2.AccountNo=t1.AccountNo

Answer (score 0):

The below query should fetch the required details. What it will do is - 
Traverse through all the accounts and then fetch the different employee names as per employee type. You can also do it with joins.

```
SELECT account.branchid BranchID,
    account.accountno AccountNo,
    (SELECT employeename
    FROM history
    WHERE account.branch_id  = history.branch_id
    AND account.accountno    = history.accountno
    AND history.employeetype = 'PMO'
    ) PMOName,
    (SELECT employeename
    FROM history
    WHERE account.branch_id  = history.branch_id
    AND account.accountno    = history.accountno
    AND history.employeetype = 'RO'
    ) ROName,
    (SELECT employeename
    FROM history
    WHERE account.branch_id  = history.branch_id
    AND account.accountno    = history.accountno
    AND history.employeetype = 'Ref'
    ) RefName
FROM account
;
```

Comment: Not working for each account number, maximum are returning empty row.

Comment: @KayserAhmed Then there might be different values in your `employeetype` field or less data in `history` table

Answer (score 0):

It's basic pivot query:

```
select * 
  from account join history using (branchid, accountno)
  pivot (max(employeename) for employeetype in ('PMO' pmo, 'RO' ro, 'Ref' ref))
  order by branchid, accountno
```

---

```
BRANCHID ACCOUNTNO PMO        RO         REF
-------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     101    123456 Mr. ABC    Mr. TRY    Mr. OPR
     102    123456 Mr. WER               Mr. CVB
     102    123457 Mr. QSR    Mr. LIT    Mr. GHK
```